# How do I tackle with the "[Errno 30] Read-only file system" error, while trying to open an xlsx in a firebase cloud function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, email-attachments, xlsxwriter

I am trying to attach this fileX to an email using a python-based cloud-function. The code runs fine on localhost while it gives this error when I deploy the cloud-function:
[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'fileX.xlsx'

Have tried writing to the /tmp directory in google cloud storage, but to no resolve.

```
    df_en.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='en')
    df_hi.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='hi')
    writer.save()
```

```
    filename = "fileX.xlsx"
    attachment = open("/tmp/fileX.xlsx", "r+b")
```

Comment: If it's read-only, open it for reading only. `r+` means both reading and writing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your need, you can either change your file's permissions in order to make it both readable and writable or change the way you attach it by changing the `"r+b"` in `"r"`.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Functions runtime is read-only except for `/tmp`.

Take a look at [Google Clould Functions deploy: EROFS: read-only file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308489/google-clould-functions-deploy-erofs-read-only-file-system)